# Upload/Download local host directory folder results in URL not found

Tags: php, local

I seem to be having some issue getting a simple PDF to display in the browser through local host.

I am using PHP "move upload file" to a directory which is working fine.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'TM470/FileServer/EmployeeCorrespondence/' . $filename;
```

There is also call to Mysql that saves the URL

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO files (name, size, path) VALUES ('$filename', '$destination')";
```

Again no issues with the call to mysql.

When I pull the URL out from MySQL which I display as an HREF Anchor, the URL is below which throws a 404 URL can't be found.

```
http://localhost/Users/MyUserName/Sites/TM470/FileServer/EmployeeCorrespondence/drawing.pdf
```

If I then remove the the /Users/MyUserName/Sites part the URL works fine.

I am clearly missing something here but not sure what?

My server root is set to DocumentRoot "/Users/MyUserName/Sites/" in the http.d config. Is this where the issue is? Should I start at the Site location?

Comment: Yes, your URL needs to be _relative to_ the document root (actually, more specifically, it needs to be relative to the page where you're displaying the link). It should never include the root, as that's a path on disk, not a URL that the webserver will serve.

Comment: P.S. **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Brill Assumed that was what was going on and yes will start to sure up the code, I always start with trying to get it working correctly first. Also this is a project and will never be in a Live system, however because I need to ensure integrity and security will be a big review section.

Comment: Just out fo curiosity, when using the Move_file_upload I can't specify a relative path only absolute, how do I get around that problem?

Comment: you mean move_uploaded_file? You can't, that saves to disk so it needs an absolute path filesystem path. This is not the same as the URL the a browser needs in order to access the image via the webserver. Don't get mixed up between URLs and filesystem paths in your head. In some cases they can map onto each other to some extent, but not always. Anyway use the full filesystem path for saving, and the relative path for generating a link in your web page.

Comment: Yes I meant move_uploaded_file. Awesome thanks for the response